# Ввод значений с помощью javascript на swf объект

Tags: javascript

Есть такой swf объект:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="SWFLoader.swf" width="800" height="100%">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
        <param name="flashvars" value="setLoc=ru">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
</object>
```

Визуально выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью javascript ввести значение формы?

Comment: зависит от _SWFLoader.swf_ и того какие методы он предоставляет

Comment: Вероятно можно решить передачей параметра из `JS` в флешку, например, через `SetVariable` (больше читаем тут: http://javascript.ru/unsorted/bridge-to-flash )

Comment: А влиять `JS` на ролик не в силах.